# Drupal 8, save new fieldCollection items to user from a foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: 8, users, entities

My user structure have a multiple field "foo" of type "FieldCollection". From a custom module, I want create programmatically several fieldcollection item and add them to the current user.

Without any loop, when I add only one new FieldCollection item to the user, its work. But, when I want user a loop for add several FieldCollection, only the first item is added. I mean :

With some light php :

```
// In my module
    // some operations and prepare the datas structure
    foreach(datas as data){ // count(datas) = 2, by example
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $field_collection_foo = FieldCollectionItem::create(array('field_name' => "field_foo"));
        $field_collection_foo->set("field_data",$data);       
        $field_collection_foo->setHostEntity($user);
        $field_collection_foo->save();
    }
```

Then if I go to the user edit page from the back office, I see only the item datas[0] added, not datas[0] datas[1]

Where is my mistake ?

UPDATE (add some test) :

I think I find, I do an another $user->save somewhere in my module and I think its it who save the wrong value :) Ill test it

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've configured the **cardinality** of the field collection `foo` as **unlimited** (or at least anything more than 1) under "Field settings".

Also double check the name that you are passing to the `FieldCollectionItem::create()` method. It shouldn't be the label name but the **machine name** of your `foo` field collection, which will probably be `field_foo`:

```
$field_collection_foo = FieldCollectionItem::create(
  array('field_name' => "field_foo")
);
```

This also applies to the `subfield_data` (in your field collection item):

```
$field_collection_foo->set("field_subfield_data", $data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) its an ilimited field, I can add manually multiple value from the edit page by example. The 'field_' missing is a copy mistake, Ill correct my main post. As I said, after my foreach instruction I see the first data in the collection field. Ill do some test, Ill add them in my main post

Comment: Ok, I see now.  A minor side-note: I'd move the `User::load()` out of the `foreach()` right above it so you won't be loading the user multiple times but only once.

Comment: Yes , it was that , my problem is solved :)